# How to limit nth records return in left join table in symfony QueryBuilder

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

I’ve been stuck with the problem of returning the left join **Vote** table limit records of **50 rows of each Answer** . The **answers** table have **one to many relationship** with **votes** table. How can i limit the **first 50 rows of vote per answer**? is Query builder allow to have limit of left join table?

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()->createQueryBuilder();
$results = $query
         ->select('a')
         ->addSelect('v')
         ->from('answers', 'a')
         ->leftJoin('votes', 'v')
         ->orderBy('v.postedTime', 'ASC')
         ->getQuery()
         ->getArrayResult();
```

If QueryBuilder not able achive how about create raw query?

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()->createQuery(
            "SELECT a.*, v.*
                FROM answer a
                LEFT JOIN a.votes v
                ORDER BY v.postedTime ASC
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Hy! Try it, there are inaccuracies due to the fact that I don't know the full context. If you see fundamental errors, please write

```
$numberVotes = 50;
$firstNumberVotesQuery = $this->getDoctrine()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('vote.id as vote_id')
    ->from(Vote::class, 'Vote')
    ->where('Vote.answer = Answer')
    ->orderBy('Vote.id', 'ASC')
    ->setMaxResults($numberVotes)
;


$query = $this->getDoctrine()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('Answer', 'Vote')
    ->from(Answer::class, 'Answer')
    ->leftjoin('Answer.votes', 'Vote', 'WITH', $qb->expr()->in('Vote.id', '(' . $firstNumberVotesQuery->getDql()  . ')'))
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
;
```

In SQL it should be something like this I think

```
SELECT *
FROM answer
LEFT JOIN vote ON answer.id = vote.answer_id AND vote.id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM vote first_50_votes
    WHERE first_50_votes.answer_id = answer.id
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 50
)
```